# Why is React menu pick not maintaining selection?

Tags: reactjs, select, drop-down-menu, onchange

I am trying to figure out why the menu pick for a note's Folder Name is not getting selected in the code below. I'm using the  tags around the folder options. The user can select the Folder Name for the note being created from the UI, but the UI doesn't maintain the selection. As a result, the note is not getting saved to any of the folders.

```
import React, { Component } from 'react'
import NotesContext from './notesContext'
import './addNote.css'

class AddNote extends Component {
    static contextType = NotesContext
    constructor(props) {
        super(props);
        this.state = {
            name: '',
            value: '',
            id: '',
            folderId: '',
            content: ""
        }
        this.handleChange = this.handleChange.bind(this);
        this.handleSubmit = this.handleSubmit.bind(this);
    }

    handleChange(event) {
        console.log("handleChange value: " + event.target.value);
        console.log("handleChange name: " + event.target.name)    
        this.setState(
            {[event.target.name]: event.target.value}
        );
    }

    handleSubmit(event) {
        console.log("this.context: " + JSON.stringify(this.context))
        event.preventDefault();
        let requestOptions = {
          method: 'POST',
          headers: {
            "Content-Type": "application/json"
          },
          body: JSON.stringify({
              "name": this.state.name,
              "id": this.state.id,
              "folderId": this.state.folderId,
              "modified": new Date().toISOString(),
              "content": this.state.content
            })
        };
        fetch("http://localhost:9090/notes/", requestOptions)
          .then(response => response.json())
          .then(result => {
              console.log("result:" + JSON.stringify(result));
              this.context.addNote(
                  result.name, 
                  result.id, 
                  result.folderId, 
                  result.modified,
                  result.content
                );
              this.props.history.push("/");
            })
          .catch(error => console.log('error', error));
    }

    render() {
        let notesContext = this.context
        return (
            <form 
                className="AddNote" 
                onSubmit={e => this.handleSubmit(e)}
            >
                <h1>Create a note</h1>
                <label>
                    Note Name:{' '}
                    <input 
                        type="text" 
                        value={this.state.name}
                        className="NameInput" 
                        name="name" 
                        id="name"
                        onChange={(e) => this.handleChange(e)}
                    />
                </label>

                <label>
                    Content:{' '}
                    <textarea
                        className="ContentInput" 
                        name="content" 
                        id="content"  
                        onChange={e => this.handleChange(e)}
                    />
                </label>

                <label>
                    Folder:{' '}
                    <select 
                        value={this.state.folderId} onChange={ (e) => this.handleChange(e)}>
                        {notesContext.folders.map(folder => {
                            return(
                                <option 
                                    value={folder.name} 
                                    name={folder.name} 
                                    key={folder.id}>{folder.name}
                                </option>
                            )
                        })}
                    </select>
                </label>

                <input 
                    type="submit" 
                    value="Submit"
                    className="SubmitButton"
                />
            </form>
        );
    }
}

export default AddNote;
```

Answer (score 0):

I have a partial Answer at this point. I split up the handleChange method for setting the note and folder. This is now allowing me to create the note in the selected folder -- only if I select a new folder, not the folder selected by default. So I still need to fix that part.

```
import React, { Component } from 'react'
import NotesContext from './notesContext'
import './addNote.css'

class AddNote extends Component {
    static contextType = NotesContext
    constructor(props) {
        super(props);
        this.state = {
            name: 'Cows',
            id: '',
            folderId: '',
            content: "",
            value: '',
        }
        this.handleChangeOfNote = this.handleChangeOfNote.bind(this);
        this.handleChangeOfFolder = this.handleChangeOfFolder.bind(this);
        this.handleSubmit = this.handleSubmit.bind(this);
    }

    handleChangeOfNote(event) {
        //console.log("handleChange value: " + event.target.value);
        //console.log("handleChange name: " + event.target.name);
        this.setState(
            {[event.target.name]: event.target.value}
        );
    }

    handleChangeOfFolder(event) {
        this.setState(
            {folderId: event.target.value}
        );
    }

    handleSubmit(event) {
        event.preventDefault();
        let requestOptions = {
          method: 'POST',
          headers: {
            "Content-Type": "application/json"
          },
          body: JSON.stringify({
              "name": this.state.name,
              "id": this.state.id,
              "folderId": this.state.folderId,
              "modified": new Date().toISOString(),
              "content": this.state.content
            })
        };
        fetch("http://localhost:9090/notes/", requestOptions)
          .then(response => response.json())
          .then(result => {
              console.log("result:" + JSON.stringify(result));
              this.context.addNote(
                  result.name, 
                  result.id, 
                  result.folderId, 
                  result.modified,
                  result.content
                );
              this.props.history.push("/");
            })
          .catch(error => console.log('error', error));
    }

    render() {
        let notesContext = this.context
        return (
            <form 
                className="AddNote" 
                onSubmit={e => this.handleSubmit(e)}
            >
                <h1>Create a note</h1>
                <label>
                    Note Name:{' '}
                    <input 
                        type="text" 
                        value={this.state.name}
                        className="NameInput" 
                        name="name" 
                        id="name"
                        onChange={(e) => this.handleChangeOfNote(e)}
                    />
                </label>

                <label>
                    Content:{' '}
                    <textarea
                        className="ContentInput" 
                        name="content" 
                        id="content"  
                        onChange={e => this.handleChangeOfNote(e)}
                    />
                </label>

                <label>
                    Folder:{' '}
                    <select 
                        value={this.state.folderId} onChange={(e) => this.handleChangeOfFolder(e)}>
                        {notesContext.folders.map(folder => {
                            return(
                                <option 
                                    value={folder.id} 
                                    name={folder.name} 
                                    key={folder.id}>{folder.name}
                                </option>
                            )
                        })}
                    </select>
                </label>

                <input 
                    type="submit" 
                    value="Submit"
                    className="SubmitButton"
                />
            </form>
        );
    }
}

export default AddNote;
```

Answer (score 0):

To fix the problem with the default folder getting set, for now I just set the folderId in state, so that it would be there by default.

```
constructor(props) {
    super(props);
    this.state = {
        name: '',
        id: '',
        folderId: 'b0715efe-ffaf-11e8-8eb2-f2801f1b9fd1',
        content: "",
        value: '',
    }
```